# Passing data from form in html to views.py not working

Tags: html, django

I passed the id value from html form to views .py. I want to check if the value matches with the one in database. But for some reason it's not working.

list.html

```
<form method= 'POST' action = "{% url 'jobs:pinned'%}">
{% csrf_token%}

 <input type ="text" name = "number">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def pinned(request,category_slug=None):

    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
    jobs_list1 = Jobs.objects.all()
    if request.method =="POST":
         vari = request.GET.get('number')
    for evert in jobs_list1:
        if evert.Job_Id == vari:
            evert.flag = True
            evert.save(update_fields=["flag"])

    context = {
        'job_list1':jobs_list1,
        'users':users
    }

    return render(request, 'jobs/product/list.html',context)
```

Here, if i put a static value as 511, i.e `if evert.Job_Id ==511`, it works. But if i change it to request.GET.get('number'), it's not working. How do i send value from form input value to views.py. Thanks.

Comment: Your using `POST` request in form and trying to get the values using `GET` in python side.

if the request type is `POST` need to use `request.POST.get('key', None)` 

if the request type is `GET` need to use `request.GET.get('key', None)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly method of your form is **POST**, so for **GET** method it will work.

for post method try this

```
     vari = request.POST.get('number')
```

hope it helps

Comment: @TulasiPrasadBanstola what does **vari** prints ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I was comparing string with an integer. Thus I solved this problem as:

```
if request.method =="POST":
        vari = request.POST.get('number')
        vari = int(vari)
        for evert in jobs_list1:
            vari1 = evert.Job_Id
.....
```